# Proper way to assert text in Selenium Webdriver/RSpec

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec

So im writing a framework in pure selenium-webdriver and am curious what the proper way to assert text exists (Such as in an alert message for instance on an invalid login for example). Specifically with RSpec.

I can think of two ways that comes to mind. Doing something like so:

1. `text_to_check = driver.find_element(locator).text` and then doing something like `expect(text_to_check).to be("Bad Login text")` The locator in this case would probably be xpath or css locator I guess? Although I feel like xpath would probably make more sense (Im not super familiar with xpath tbh though)
2. Use the `driver.page_source()` and then check against that....but that seems brittle if that text exists somewhere else on the page. Also it seems unnecessary to do that and pull in the whole page source to check what is essentially one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. String expected = “abc.com;
   String actualURL= “abc.com”;
   Assert.assertEquals(expected, actualURL);
2. message – Message to be displayed in case of an Assertion Error.
   condition – Condition against which the assertion needs to be applied.
   Assert.assertTrue(“Assert True test message”, true);